# Get the Angular UI Router's state by its URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a `/login?next` state, where the `next` parameter is a given URL. I would like to fetch and evaluate its state and use `state.go(state)`, but I can't find a way to turn `/login?next=/preferences` to its `user.preferences` state.

Comment: I have a similar situation. Something like `$location.path($location.search().next)` worked for me (even with angular-ui-router), but it would be best to actual get the state to use `$state.go()`

Comment: Have you figured this out ?

Comment: Cant be done. This just wasnt implemented.